# How to target a TOC after generating via inDesign's createTOC function

Tags: javascript, object, adobe-indesign, tableofcontents

I'm trying to target a table of contents object that is generated by inDesign's createTOC function. I am successfully generating the object, but I can not set any kind of identifier properties like `tocTF.name = "myToc"` When I examine it in the Data Browser it is being identified as an [object Story] but without any properties except for length. I was also able to find it as a textFrame in it's containing layer when I was trying to troubleshoot in the console.

**Function in Use**

```
tocTF = doc.createTOC(tocStyle, true, undefined, [margins[1]+"px",  margins[0]+"px"], true, tocFolder);
```

**Data Browser**

[image: Data Browser Screen Shot]

**Console**

> doc.layers.item(tocFolderName).textFrames.length 
>   Result: 1
>   doc.layers.item(tocFolderName).textFrames.item(0).id
>   Result: 447428
>   doc.layers.item(tocFolderName).textFrames.item(0).name
>   Result:

Although it's returning an ID number, I cannot use this for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You access it via Story not TextFrame. TOC is a type of story.

```
for (var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.stories.length; i++) {
    if (app.activeDocument.stories [i].storyType == StoryTypes.TOC_STORY) {
      //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

You then can access the text box holding the story like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.stories.length; i++) {
    if (app.activeDocument.stories [i].storyType == StoryTypes.TOC_STORY) {
        var toc_story = app.activeDocument.stories [i];
        var text_frame = toc_story.textContainers [0];
    }
}
```

More on that [here](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Story.html).